# Show that $| f (0)| ≤ \sqrt{6}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $f$ is $C$-analytic in $|z| ≤ 1$, $f ≪ 2$ for $|z| = 1$, Im $z ≥ 0$ and $f ≪ 3$ for $|z| = 1$, Im $z ≤ 0$. Show then that $| f (0)| ≤ \sqrt{6}$.

I know to consider $f(z)f(-z)$ but not sure where to go from here. How can I prove this ?

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Since you already know that the key is to consider $g(z) = f(z)\cdot f(-z)$, what do you know about $g$?

Comment: I don't know.. Does this have to do with the maximum not being within the radius $|z|≤1$ ?

Comment: Ok so $g(z)$ is bounded in modulus by 6 throughout $|z|≤1$. Thus $|g(0)| ≤6$ and $|f(0)| ≤ 6^{1/2}$.  Why is this true though?

Comment: Right. I'm not sure what you want to hear about why this is true. Why is $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 6$? There's your reason.